# Receiving a mail in the class

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to get a message using `import javax.mail.*`.

Here, everything works:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore(provider);
try {
    store.connect(host, username, password);
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    if (inbox == null) {
        System.out.println("No INBOX");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Message " + (i + 1));
        messages[i].writeTo(System.out);
    }
    inbox.close(false);
    store.close();
}
catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
```

But if you take the receipt of mail in a separate class, then there is an error "Exception in thread" main "javax.mail.MessagingException: Not connected"

Caller:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore(provider);
Mail mail=new Mail();
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
store.connect(host, username, password);
inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
mail.GetMessage(host,username,password,inbox,store);
```

Class Mail:

```
public void GetMessage(String host,String username,String password,Folder inbox,Store store) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    try {
        inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        if (inbox == null) {
            System.out.println("No INBOX");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Message " + (i + 1));
            messages[i].writeTo(System.out);
        }
        inbox.close(false);
        store.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You've broken your encapsulation.  `Mail.GetMessage()` should either take the host/username/password and connect to the mail server itself, **or** it should take the `store` (and a folder name), and `getFolder()` on that, **or** it should take an already found `Folder inbox` and operate on that.  But you shouldn't be closing the `store` inside `GetMessage()` if `GetMessage()` didn't open it, or you're likely to find the second time you try to retrieve mail, your store has been closed or corrupted.  Restructure your code with proper encapsulation.

Comment: You should also look at the stack trace and identify the line where the exception is being raised, **and include that in your problem description**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is a simple order-of-operations error, and unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the caller, move

```
store.connect(host, username, password);
```

before

```
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
```

And remove in Mail Class

```
inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
```

it's useless since you're doing it the caller.

PS. To follow Java naming standard, rename your *GetMessage()* method to *getMessage()*.

Answer (score 1):

[Change Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#getdefaultinstance)

Your code is confused about what it's doing with "inbox".  Your GetMessage method is overwriting the parameter without using it.

The problem is because your calling code is trying to get the INBOX folder before it has connected to the Store.  If you remove uses of "inbox" in the calling code, it will work, and make much more sense!